# Query INFORMATION_SCHEMA for list of indexes

Tags: index, information-schema

How does one query [`INFORMATION_SCHEMA`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_schema) in a standards-compliant database such as [Postgres](http://www.postgresql.org) to obtain a list of all indexes in one database/catalog?

Comment: [This Answer](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/63853/19079) by [Bill Karwin](http://dba.stackexchange.com/users/2703/bill-karwin) said No. He explains indexes are an implementation-detail rather than a standard feature. So, not listed in `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.